# Is there any R function that I can use to calculate e^π and π^e?

Tags: r

I am trying to compare the values e^π and π^e using R. However I keep getting the message object 'e' not found.

Comment: ```> exp(1)
[1] 2.718282
> pi
[1] 3.141593```

Comment: Use `e <- exp(1)`

Answer (score 0):

`e` isn't automatically defined in R, but it can be obtained with `exp(1)`, so you can do `exp(1) ^ pi` and `pi ^ exp(1)`